# Solving variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help solving for the variable in the equations in the image. If you could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

I have the following equations $e^{y}=9$, and $7^{x+9}=5$.

I got $y=2\ln(3)$ and $x=\displaystyle \frac{\log(5)}{\log(7)}-9$

Comment: Hi shyanne. Linking to an image is not considered ideal etiquette on Math.SE, especially when the problem is short. Instead, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. You should also demonstrate that you've made an effort to solve the problem on your own by showing us what you've done so far. Following these guidelines will increase the probability of a response (and decrease the probability of receiving downvotes).

Comment: y=ln9, x=log7(5)-9, so you have the correct answers. good job

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: @parsiad Thanks for your input I'm trying to figure out how to use mathjax and I just posted what I got when trying to solve it myself.

Comment: @shyanne i reformatted it for you?

Comment: @SakethMalyala Thanks so much!

Comment: @SakethMalyala: The text "I need help solving for the variable in the equations in the image. If you could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you" is no longer relevant; consider removing.

Comment: One way to learn MathJax is to right click on some and select Show Math As ->TeX commands.  It will open a window that shows how it was done.

Answer (score 4):

The first is not correct
$$e^y=9\\y=\log 9\\y=\log\left(3^2\right)\\y=2 \log 3$$

Comment: Oh my goodness. @shyanne actually solved it correctly as 2log3, but when I converted her images to text, I copied it as 3log2